# is calling functions from within other functions bad practice?

Tags: c++

I was wanting to ask fellow developers on there opinions on this topic. Basically im working on a project which I didn't design. I'm here to fix up the code and make it as modular and maintainable as possible.

Now, the problem is most classes are well over 3000 lines long :S nightmare.

there are third party libraries in place to help aid with UI design and the code is not very pretty for the most part, especially when it comes to maintaining it which im attempting to do.

I ask, do you feel it is bad practice to call a number of functions from within a function? since the majority of this code is relevant to the class, and its very difficult to break out into another class without passing everything as a parameter ^^. So what I have been doing is breaking out specific functions into separate methods and calling from the method in which they originally derived.

Can someone perhaps shed some light on what they think the best approach should be?

I much appreciate any feedback on this discussion.

Comment: This may be a fit for programmers.SE, where it will be downvoted or closed.  But it's out of scope here; there is no specific problem to solve.

Comment: If you _didn't_ call other member functions you could very well end up with an extra zero on the line count.

Comment: This is true, although it will help modularise and help maintain the code it will push the number of lines. So the balance between quantity and maintainability is hard to decide, hence the reason I ask do you think its a good approach to break it up into smaller functions and call them.

Comment: @djechlin, I feel this is a valid question, I just want to see what the majority would recommend here.

Comment: That is wrong; see e.g. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Answer (score 5):

It's not bad practice.  It's generally good practice.  I refer you to Steve McConnell's *Code Complete* 1st edition chapters 4-5 for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for that reference, ill have a look over those chapters tonight, thanks :)